# Confusion on printing strings as integers in C

Tags: c, string, integer

I would like to know how the string is represented in integer, so I wrote the following program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char name[4] = {"@"};  
  printf("integer name %d\n", *(int*)name);  
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
integer name 64
```

This is understandable because `@` is `64` in integer, i.e., `0x40` in hex.

Now I change the program into:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
  char name[4] = {"@@"};  
  printf("integer name %d\n", *(int*)name);  
  return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
integer name 16448
```

I dont understand this. Since `@@` is `0x4040` in hex. So it should be `2^12+2^6 = 4160`
If I count the `'\0'` at the end of the string, then it should be `2^16+2^10 = 66560`

Could someone explain where `16448` comes from?

Comment: 64 + 64 * 2^8 -> 16448

Comment: your architecture is little endian.  so the series of 4 chars (that is the size of an int) is 0x40400000  and looking at it, as if it were big endian = 0x00004040.  now, converting hex to decimal is 16448

Comment: Indeed, simple math error you have there. Also, your raw nemory contents are 40000000 and 40400000 hex, *little endian*, so integers 0x00000040 and 0x00004040.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your math is wrong: `0x4040 == 16448`. The two fours are the 6<sup>th</sup> and *14*<sup>th</sup> bits respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Your code actually invokes undefined behavior because you must not alias a `char *` with an `int *`.  This is known as the [*strict aliasing rule*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98650/what-is-the-strict-aliasing-rule).  To see just one reason why this *should* be disallowed, consider what would otherwise have to happen if the code is run on a little and a big endian machine.

If you want to see the hex pattern of the string, you should simply loop over its bytes and print out each byte.

```
void
print_string(const char * strp)
{
  printf("0x");
  do
    printf("%02X", (unsigned char) *strp);
  while (*strp++);
  printf("\n");
}
```

Of course, instead of printing the bytes, you can shift them into an integer (that will very soon overflow) and only finally output that integer.  While doing this, you'll be forced to take a stand on “your” endianness.

```
/* Interpreting as big endian. */
unsigned long
int_string(const char * strp)
{
  unsigned long value = 0UL;
  do
    value = (value << 8) | (unsigned char) *strp;
  while (*strp++);
  return value;
}
```

Comment: `printf("%02X", *strp);` runs into a minor problem when `*strp` is negative.  Maybe `printf("%02hhX", *strp);`

Comment: Alias a `char *` with an `int *` is also UB due to alignment requirements.  A mis-aligned `char*` could bus-fault.

Comment: *Pedantic*, actually it isn't allowed because Standard says so, not because of endianness. Still great that you pointed it out.

Comment: @chux Good point, it shouldn't happen with ASCII but I've added a cast to `unsigned char` just in case.  This should solve the issue.

Comment: @2501 Of course.  I thought it would become clear that it is forbidden but if possible, I always like to give a short rational why the standard disallowed something.  To make this more clear, I have now incorporated the term *strict aliasing rule* and linked to the relevant question which already has a very good answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is how `16448` comes :

0x4040 can be written like this in binary :

```
   4    0    4    0   -> Hex
 0100 0000 0100 0000  -> Binary
 2^14      2^6        =  16448
```

Because here 6th and 14th bit are set.
Hope you got it :)